# Java list.contains returning false, should be true

Tags: java, undefined-behavior

Okay, I was trying to do some conditional checks and noticed this returned false.... Something I'm missing?

```
int test = 1;

int[] testing= {1,3};

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(testing).contains(test) );  //false???
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` is a generic method where the generic type variable is used in the vararg parameter. Primitive types don't work with generics.

Therefore, after

```
Arrays.asList(testing)
```

the `List` returned contains a single element, an array of type `int`.

Your test would pass if `testing` was declared as an `Integer[]`.

Comment: Wont java autobox it?

Comment: @DanielFigueroa Not for array types.

Comment: Autoboxing is for individual primitives, not arrays of them.

Comment: another reason to use c#!!! :P